# Difference between buffered io and unbuffered io

Tags: c, linux, io, buffer

i have a question about buffer in I/O programming in C.
For example, it is always said that *fwrite* is a buffered i/o, and *write* is an unbuffered i/o. My understanding is that the 'buffered' here is in application layer, and i think in kernel level, they both have a buffer. From APUE, i saw:

> Traditional implementations of the UNIX System havea buffer cache or
>   page cache in the kernel throughwhich  most disk I/O passes. When we
>   write data to a file,the data is normally copied by the kernel into
>   oneof its  buffers and queued for writing to disk at some later time.
>   This is called delayed write.

Am i right? So i do a experiment:

```
 int main() {
    char *fname = "helloworld";
    char content[] = "abcdefg";
    int fd = open(fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    int flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    flag &= ~O_SYNC;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flag);
    write(fd, content, 3);
    sleep(100);
    return 0;
   }
```

I thought there should be nothing outputed during sleep, but the fact is the opposite.
Is there something i misunderstood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple layers of buffering.  If you call `write`, no application layer buffering will occur.  If you look at the file from another process you will see the data, but that does not mean they have been committed to disk, because there is a layer of buffering happening in the kernel.  Since the kernel is handling the access from the other process, it is reporting the data in the buffer to that other process.  In other words, from the perspective of all user-space applications the data has been written to the file, but it has not actually hit the disk.

Comment: Thank you very much! And may i ask another problem? I think you are right and i try to experiment again on a virtual machine. The code is the same, and i TURN OFF the virtual machine when the process is in sleep. i thought the data in kernel buffer should vanish when power down. But the data is stiil written to the file when i power it up again. Is there some other techonology that will have an effect on the I/O in this case? May DMA or something else play a role here?

Comment: The sleep(100) is totally irrelevant.  The kernel probably only buffers the data for a few milliseconds, at most.  When you turn off the virtual machine, it will flush its buffers and sync to the disk.